# Changing the background color of a select2 selection within the select field

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-select2

I am using Select2 to setup multi-select tag type fields in my application. I know which CSS attribute changes the colors of the selection box once it is placed in the select field:

**selection box color**

```
.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice {
    background-color: #e4e4e4;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: default;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding: 0 5px
}
```

What I am trying to figure out is how to have this change based on the selection a user makes. The selection list is pre-defined.

Tried something like this:

**JavaScript to initialize / change box color**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#test').select2();
        $('.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice').each(function () {
            var title = $(this).attr('title');
            console.log(title);
            if (title === 'Breakfast') {
                $(this).parent().css({ 'background-color': "green" });
            }
            if (title === 'Brunch') {
                $(this).parent().css({ 'background-color': "red" });
            }
            if (title === 'Lunch') {
                $(this).parent().css({ 'background-color': "blue" });
            }
        });
    });
```

This does not appear to work. Has anyone tried styling the tag boxes for Select2?

Comment: I'd suggest to override the styles instead of setting them via javascript. The plugin is open source, so the stylesheets are available on github as scss files: https://github.com/select2/select2/tree/master/src/scss. If you use bootstrap, use the files from this repository https://github.com/select2/select2-bootstrap-theme/tree/master/src

Answer (score 1):

Change  `$(this).parent().css('background-color', 'green');`

by `$(this).parent().css({ 'background-color': "green" });`

And the same with the rest.